# Parsing cookie content

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have been trying to parse the following cookie content . I am using Jquery cookie plugin but not able to extract the value of keys like total_items etc. I tried to convert string to objects but couldn't .

```
a:7:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"40049f03b718307f940c56da070646e1";s:10:"ip_address";s:13:"xxx.xx.1x1.97";s:10:"user_agent";s:108:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";s:13:"last_activity";i:1489319410;s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:7:"facelog";s:8:"facebook";s:13:"cart_contents";a:5:{s:32:"34173cb38f07f89ddbebc2ac9128303f";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"34173cb38f07f89ddbebc2ac9128303f";s:2:"id";s:2:"30";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:4:"3.50";s:4:"name";s:5:"Pulao";s:8:"subtotal";d:3.5;}s:32:"c16a5320fa475530d9583c34fd356ef5";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"c16a5320fa475530d9583c34fd356ef5";s:2:"id";s:2:"31";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:4:"3.00";s:4:"name";s:10:"Plain Rice";s:8:"subtotal";d:3;}s:32:"6364d3f0f495b6ab9dcf8d3b5c6e0b01";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"6364d3f0f495b6ab9dcf8d3b5c6e0b01";s:2:"id";s:2:"32";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:4:"2.00";s:4:"name";s:13:"Tandoori Roti";s:8:"subtotal";d:2;}s:11:"total_items";i:3;s:10:"cart_total";d:8.5;}}bd6efb422491bf1ae129c0492dc108b4
```

Can anyone put me on the right track ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to be an object serialized with PHP. I suggest converting it to JSON instead of to a PHP serialization when creating the cookie. If you can't do that (for example, because you don't run the server-side of the application), you can use PHP.js http://locutus.io/php/var/unserialize/ .

Answer (score 1):

This will turn it into a standard javascript object using plain javascript:

```
var cookie = 'a:7:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"40049f03b718307f940c56da070646e1";s:10:"ip_address";s:13:"xxx.xx.1x1.97";s:10:"user_agent";s:108:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";s:13:"last_activity";i:1489319410;s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:7:"facelog";s:8:"facebook";s:13:"cart_contents";a:5:{s:32:"34173cb38f07f89ddbebc2ac9128303f";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"34173cb38f07f89ddbebc2ac9128303f";s:2:"id";s:2:"30";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:4:"3.50";s:4:"name";s:5:"Pulao";s:8:"subtotal";d:3.5;}s:32:"c16a5320fa475530d9583c34fd356ef5";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"c16a5320fa475530d9583c34fd356ef5";s:2:"id";s:2:"31";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:4:"3.00";s:4:"name";s:10:"Plain Rice";s:8:"subtotal";d:3;}s:32:"6364d3f0f495b6ab9dcf8d3b5c6e0b01";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"6364d3f0f495b6ab9dcf8d3b5c6e0b01";s:2:"id";s:2:"32";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:4:"2.00";s:4:"name";s:13:"Tandoori Roti";s:8:"subtotal";d:2;}s:11:"total_items";i:3;s:10:"cart_total";d:8.5;}}bd6efb422491bf1ae129c0492dc108b4';

  function parseRecursive(obj,str) {
    var foundkey = false;
    var key;
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;) {
      switch(str.charAt(i)) {      
        case "}":
          i++;
          return(i);
        case "a":
          i = str.indexOf("{",i) + 1;
          if(foundkey == true) {
            var obj2 = {}
            i += parseRecursive(obj2,str.substring(i));
            obj[key] = obj2;
            foundkey = false;
          }
          else console.log("found { with no key");
          break;
        case "i":
          i += 2;
          j = str.indexOf(';',i);
          obj[key] = parseInt(str.substring(i,j));
          foundkey = false;
          i = j+1;
          break;
        case "d":
          i += 2;
          j = str.indexOf(';',i);
          obj[key] = parseFloat(str.substring(i,j));
          foundkey = false;
          i = j+1;
          break;
        case "s":
          i = str.indexOf('"',i) + 1;
          j = str.indexOf('"',i) + 1;
          if(foundkey == false) {
            key = str.substring(i,j-1);
            foundkey = true;          
          }
          else {
            obj[key] = str.substring(i,j-1);
            foundkey = false;
          }
          i = j+1;
          break;
        default:
          i++;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  function parse(obj,str) {
    // skip to the first open brace and start recursive object parsing there
    var i = str.indexOf("{") + 1;
    parseRecursive(obj,str.substring(i));
  }
  var obj = {};
  parse(obj,cookie);
  console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you , I will surely try this :)